# Relation between exacte controlability and stability.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, control-theory

In general when we talk about controlability we talk about proving the existence of control to remain the state to another state at desired time $T$, but in stability we proof that the solution tends to zero when $t$ tends to infinity, my question is: Is there any relation between stability(exponential, polynomial, strong) and controlability(approximate or exact, null) of PDE? Thank you.

Comment: Your question is interesting but you should add more details or it will be closed.

Comment: Thank you sir for your interesting, I want to know if there is any relation between stability of linear evolution pde and  the existence of control, it is well known that the feedback or dampers are a particular case of control but my question is general, does stability imply control ? thanks.

Comment: Too general questions are (sadly) quite seldom appreciated on this site. Sometimes it can help to add the "soft question" tag on them, but they are often closed for lack of context or even being off topic. Just adding some small example for people to get the context from can sometimes help get a better reception.